# How to fix the width of containers using css flex property

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three containers. In tablet portrait mode I need to arrange the width of the containers with the below specifications.

1. Container 1 and 3 should be in a single row and should be aligned to the center of the parent container 'flex container'. The width of each container 1 and 3 should be 260px each.
2. Container 2, should be below the container 1 and 3 and the width of this container should be equal to the container 1 and 3 total widths.

I will place the final solution code inside the specific media query. I am looking for a solution where the container's width should satisfy the above points.

This is what I tried:

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexcontainer > div {
  flex: 1 0 260px;
  background-color: #e46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
  margin: 3px;
}

.flex:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1 0 520px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flex"> 1 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 2 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao: I will keep the solution in the specific media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the outer width of the parent to `520px` then set the flex basis on `and 3 to`50%`and container 2 to`100%`

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 520px;
  margin: auto;
}

.flexcontainer > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background-color: #e46119;
  border: 1px solid #626262;
}

.flex:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flex"> 1 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 2 </div>
  <div class="flex"> 3 </div>
</div>
```